# How to build byte array from bytes and nibbles in C#

Tags: c#

Given this structure of a string array

```
string[] content = {"0x1", "5", "0x8", "7", "0x66"};
```

How to get the `content` equivalent byte array representation? I know how to convert the "5", "7" and "0x66" but I'm struggling to build the whole byte array representation of the nibbles `0x1`, `0x8` in the array... Basically I don't know how to concat the "`0x1"`, `"5"`, `"0x8"` to two bytes...

Additional Info: The sequence of the string array contains only byte or nibble data. Prefixed "0x" and one digit is to be intepreted as a nibble, digits without prefix should be intepreted as byte, hex strings with two numbers should be intepreted as byte.

Comment: Are you saying that some of those strings represent bytes and some represent nibbles? So anything with two digits is a byte and anything with a single digit is a nibble? Or is anything without an "0x" prefix a byte? Please be very specific about the syntax you're assuming.

Comment: `0x1` is a byte, whose least significant bit is high. Talking about nibbles would make sense only if you meant to pack two nibbles into one byte. If you did so though, you'd have no way to discern normal bytes from packed ones

Answer (score 2):

If all items are supposed to be hexadecimal, *Linq* and `Convert` are enough:

```
string[] content = {"0x1", "5", "0x8", "7", "0x66"};

byte[] result = content
  .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, 16))
  .ToArray();
```

If `"5"` and `"7"` are supposed to be *decimal* (since they *don't start* from `0x`) we have to add a condition:

```
byte[] result = content
  .Select(item => Convert.ToByte(item, item.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
    ? 16
    : 10))
  .ToArray();
```

**Edit:** If we want to *combine nibbles*, let's extract a method for it:

```
private static byte[] Nibbles(IEnumerable<string> data) {
  List<byte> list = new List<byte>();

  bool head = true;

  foreach (var item in data) {
    byte value = item.StartsWith("0x", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) 
      ? Convert.ToByte(item, 16)
      : Convert.ToByte(item, 10);

    // Do we have a nibble? 
    // 0xDigit (Length = 3) or Digit (Length = 1) are supposed to be nibble
    if (item.Length == 3 || item.Length == 1) { // Nibble
      if (head)                                 // Head
        list.Add(Convert.ToByte(item, 16));
      else                                      // Tail
        list[list.Count - 1] = (byte)(list[list.Count - 1] * 16 + value);

      head = !head;
    }
    else { // Entire byte
      head = true;

      list.Add(value);
    }
  }

  return list.ToArray();
}

...

string[] content = { "0x1", "5", "0x8", "7", "0x66" };

Console.Write(string.Join(", ", Nibbles(content)
  .Select(item => $"0x{item:x2}").ToArray()));
```

**Outcome:**

```
// "0x1", "5" are combined into 0x15
// "0x8", "7" are combined into 0x87
// "0x66"  is treated as a byte 0x66
0x15, 0x87, 0x66
```

Comment: Thanks Dmitry for your efford!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) method, to combine the source with the same source offset by 1.

```
string[] source = { "0x1", "5", "0x8", "7", "0x66" };
var offsetSource = source.Skip(1).Concat(new string[] { "" });

var bytes = source
.Zip(offsetSource, (s1, s2) => s1 + s2)
.Where(s => s.Length == 4 && s.StartsWith("0x"))
.Select(s => Convert.ToByte(s, 16))
.ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(", ", bytes)); // Output: 21, 135, 102
```